# Hypergan not training properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

#### My issue

Hello, while I was trying to train my [HyperGAN](https://github.com/HyperGAN/HyperGAN) model, I noticed that, unlike many of the YouTube Videos that I have watched on the subject, the images in the HyperGAN training window did not change very much over a large number of steps (~700). All that happened were the images changed shade a couple of times. It would be very nice if someone could let me know what causes this, wether there is an issue with the images, or if it just needs more time to train.

#### Extra details

- My model is a 32x32x3 GAN with 32x32 PNG images
- All images are in colour
- While I was training, in the Command Prompt window there was a warning: `tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:88] PNG warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`
- I am using windows 10 with tensorflow running on GPU.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: 700 isn't a large number of steps...

Comment: I just realized this is an 10 month old question. Did you get it to work? I'm training a 64x64x3 model right now. It just passed 250.000 steps and I guess it will need something like 700.000 on my dataset at this resolution to produce good images